# Override doctrine magic accessor method

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I try to override a property getter method (which is processed by sfDoctrineRecord::__call() method) like this:

```
//myClass.class.php
public function getProperty()
{
  $property = parent::getProperty();
  //the following line is never reached
  return $property;
}
```

But this results in infinite recursion. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public function getProperty()
{
  $property = $this->_get('property');
  //the following line is never reached
  return $property;
}
```

Also, read about custom mutators and accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Within the [DoctrineRecord.__call](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php.source.html#line2124) method you'll see it uses `call_user_func_array`, which will try to call the `getProperty` method of the class.

Since you've overriden `getProperty`, it's calling the child class definition, so it's calling itself.

Comment: If the `parent::getProperty()` method is using the `__call` method, then yes, overriding `getProperty` will cause `parent::getProperty()` to call the child method over and over.

I think you'll need to duplicate the functionality of the parent getProperty method in your child class to accomplish this.

However, if your child class's `getProperty` method is as simple as you show above, you should not need to override it at all. The parent's version will do what you're wanting.

Comment: No, of cause not, I was going to apply some logic. Thanks for your comments, solved it by calling _get() method directly: $property = $this->_get('Property')